# Most convenient way to set legend marker size?

Tags: plotting, legending, charts

If I add a legend using

```
Legended[..., SwatchLegend[..., ...]]
```

then I can explicitly set the legend marker size using the [`LegendMarkerSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendMarkerSize.html) option.  But I also need to explicitly set the style/colour of the legend elements a second time within the legend expression.

It is usually much more convenient to use the `PlotLegens` or the `ChartLegends` option.  It spares me the trouble of having to manually match up the legens with the plot or chart.  If I use this, can I still control the marker size?

Example:

```
cm = 72/2.54;
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}, ChartLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}, ImageSize -> 4 cm]
```

How can I control the legend marker size in the above graphic?  Is there anything simpler than an explicit legend specification as below?

```
colours = {Red, Blue, Black};
Legended[
 BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}, ImageSize -> 4 cm, ChartStyle -> colours],
 SwatchLegend[colours, {"a", "b", "c"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 7]
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always do it like this:

```
cm = 72/2.54;
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}, 
  ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"a", "b", "c"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20], ImageSize -> 4 cm]
```

top: code from your question, bottom: this code

[image]

The colors of the legend are inherited from the BarChart object:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"a", "b", "c"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20], ImageSize -> 4 cm]
```

[image]

Comment: I added back the style specification to point out that it will be inherited by the legend (as this was my problem).  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add back the style specification after your latest edit?  Without it, it is not at all apparent that this solves the problem, as both the chart and the legending shows the default colours.

Comment: Good point, I edited it and now it should be apparent that colors are inherited from chart and not just the same because default colors were used.

Answer (score 10):

For `ChartLegends`, although the documentation does not mention any values other than `"Row"` and `"Column"` for the option `LegendAppearance`, it turns out you can also use this option  to set the `LegendMarkerSize`

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
 LegendAppearance -> {LegendMarkerSize -> 20},
 ChartLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}, ImageSize -> 4 cm]
```

[image]

In fact, you can use any of the options for `SwatchLegend` as the setting for `LegendAppearance`:

```
Row[BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}, ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
             ChartLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}, ImageSize -> 4 cm,
             LegendAppearance -> #] & /@ {
                         {LegendLabel -> "legend"},
                         {LabelStyle -> Red},
                         {LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn", LegendMarkerSize -> 20},
                         {LegendLayout -> "ReversedRow", LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
                              LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"}}]
```

[image]

For `PlotLegends`, this approach does not work.

Comment: I really did think I tried this, and it didn't work.  But it does work (both in v9 and 10), and it looks to be the simplest solution.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for pointing out additional options for `LegendAppearance`.