# How to style Automatic legend labels?

Tags: legending, charts

Here's a minimal example:

```
BarChart[<|"Group A"->{4, 5, 6}, "Group B"->{1, 2, 3}|>,
  ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None},
  ChartLegends-> Placed[Automatic, {0.8, 0.8}] (*how to style legend labels?*)
]
```

How do you "pass along" the styling information in the Automatic cases?

I'd like to avoid having to manually recreate the legend:

```
Legended[
 BarChart[<|"Group A"->{4, 5, 6}, "Group B"->{1, 2, 3}|>,
  ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None}],
 Placed[
  SwatchLegend[
   ColorData["Pastel", #] & /@ {0, 1},
   {"Group A", "Group B"}, LabelStyle->30],
  {0.8, 0.8}]]
```

Comment: You can use `LegendAppearance`. Although it's not described in the documentation, it turns out that you can use any of the options for `SwatchLegend` as a setting for `LegendAppearance`. See kglr's answer to [Most convenient way to set legend marker size?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59122/27951).

Comment: That's a huge lapse in the documentation

Comment: Yes, I agree: this should definitely be better documented.